# How can I compute the chromatic index and number of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I saw a [recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13454) from M.R. and realized there is no function to compute the chromatic index and number of a graph, other than a really slow method in the now deprecated *Combinatorica*.

So, how can I compute the chromatic index and number of a graph?

Comment: Check http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6913/

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It is relevant to point out the source claims to to use the Misra-Gries algorithm, so it is not always optimal.

Answer (score 9):

You can compute the chromatic index of a graph by first observing it is equivalent to the chromatic number of the line graph of the graph. This immediately suggests straightforward algorithms:

```
ChromaticNumber[g_] := MinValue[{z, z > 0 && ChromaticPolynomial[g, z] > 0}, z, Integers];
ChromaticIndex[g_] := ChromaticNumber[LineGraph[g]];
```

Notice we make use of [`ChromaticPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticPolynomial.html) which was incorporated into the main language in V10.

Answer (score 5):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has some [graph colouring](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#graph-colouring) functionality.

Let us create a graph:

```
style = {VertexSize -> Large, 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[1]], 
   GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"};

SeedRandom[998]
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, style]
```

[image]

Compute its chromatic number and chromatic index:

```
IGChromaticNumber[g]
(* 3 *)

IGChromaticIndex[g]
(* 6 *)
```

Visualize a vertex colouring:

```
g // IGVertexMap[ColorData[100], VertexStyle -> IGMinimumVertexColoring]
```

[image]

Visualize an edge colouring:

```
g // IGEdgeMap[ColorData[100], EdgeStyle -> IGMinimumEdgeColoring]
```

[image]

Visualize an edge colouring in a non-simple graph in Mathematica 12.1:

```
mg = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {30, 2}], style];

mg // EdgeTaggedGraph // IGEdgeMap[ColorData[100], EdgeStyle -> IGMinimumEdgeColoring]
```

[image]

IGraph/M can compute a colouring for multigraphs in all supported Mathematica versions, but only Mathematica 12.1 can *visualize* them.

Comment: This should be much more efficient than the solution in my answer.