# i need a swap mutation code (genetic algorithm) in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, algorithm

I'm working on GA coding to optimize the locators position in fixturing system to minimize the error in precision manufacturing.I need a code for mutation (genetic algorithm) in Mathematica. Here, I am sharing the code which I tried to made. Kindly, help me if possible. Thanks in advance.

```
string = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
mutataionrate = .01;
domutation[string_] :=
 Module[{tempstring, i},
  tempstring = string;
  Do[If[Random[] < mutationrate,
    tempstring[[i]] = 1 - tempstring[[i]]],
   {i, StringLength}];
  Return[{tempstring}]]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at (How can I speed up the classic GA for graph coloring?)[http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13454/27951]? The question and answers contain a possible implementation of mutation.

Answer (score 4):

Since it looks like your search space is binary strings, you can take advantage of `BitXor` which is popular in GAs for toggling genes:

```
doMutation[string_, geneMutateProb_] := 
 BitXor[string, RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[geneMutateProb], Length[string]]]
```